# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'ffprobe' FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffprobe

```
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment
input_file = "audio.mp3"
output_file = "result.wav"

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(input_file)
sound.export(output_file, format="wav")
```

When i run the above code. It show below error.

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'
```

I tried this also using subprocess module.

```
input_file = "audio.mp3"
output_file = "result.wav"

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, output_file])
```

It gives below error

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
```

I'm not sure what's wrong on this code. I'm currently using **Windows 10**. Please solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Download ffmpeg from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html and add the library to your system.

Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350259/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-ffprobe-ffprobe)

Comment: Under Windows you also want to make sure that ffmpeg `bin` directory is available in PATH. Otherwise the same error will occur because `pydub` is expecting those ffmpeg tools to be available there.