# AudioSegment unable to find ffmepg and ffprobe

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am attempting to load an mp3 file in jupyter notebooks using AudioSegment in python. I have already tried following the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350259/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-ffprobe-ffprobe) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219531/pydub-unable-to-locate-ffprobe) link but I am still running into the following problems. Here is my code and the corresponding errors:

```
import sys
path_to_ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
path_to_ffprobe = "/usr/local/bin/ffprobe"
sys.path.append(path_to_ffmpeg)
sys.path.append(path_to_ffprobe)

from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
AudioSegment.ffprobe = "/usr/local/bin/ffprobe"
from ffprobe import FFProbe
```

Trying to import AudioSegment gives this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

```
filename = "file.mp3"
audiofile = AudioSegment.from_file(filename, "mp3")
audiolen = audiofile.duration_seconds #in seconds
```

Trying to load the audio file gives this erorr:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 filename = "Y2Mate.is - Teen stress from a teen perspective  Michaela Horn  TEDxNaperville-FhG-VoRtkKY-128k-1647187680543.mp3"
----> 2 audiofile = AudioSegment.from_file(filename, "mp3")
      3 audiolen = audiofile.duration_seconds

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py:728, in AudioSegment.from_file(cls, file, format, codec, parameters, start_second, duration, **kwargs)
    726     info = None
    727 else:
--> 728     info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
    729 if info:
    730     audio_streams = [x for x in info['streams']
    731                      if x['codec_type'] == 'audio']

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:274, in mediainfo_json(filepath, read_ahead_limit)
    271         file.close()
    273 command = [prober, '-of', 'json'] + command_args
--> 274 res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    275 output, stderr = res.communicate(input=stdin_data)
    276 output = output.decode("utf-8", 'ignore')

File /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:951, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
    947         if self.text_mode:
    948             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
    949                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
--> 951     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    952                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
    953                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
    954                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
    955                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
    956                         errread, errwrite,
    957                         restore_signals,
    958                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
    959                         start_new_session)
    960 except:
    961     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
    962     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:1821, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1819     if errno_num != 0:
   1820         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1821     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1822 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffprobe'
```

I am unsure how to troubleshoot this further. I am running on macOS Big Sur Version 11.1. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: If you downloaded binaries yourself (instead of using a package manager) you need to run `chmod` to make your `ffmpeg` & `ffprobe` executable.

Comment: Also, if you need an easy way out, you can use `static-ffmpeg` or `ffmpeg-downloader` (the latter, I'm the author of). Both of which will set file permissions for you after they download the executables. Furthermore, if you just need to load audio samples and not bound to `pydub`, I'd be happy to show how to use my `ffmpegio` package to achieve it fairly easily.

Comment: @kesh I actually ran chmod 755 on them just a while ago and it fixed my problem!